# OWL reasoning based on subset of relationships

Tags: owl, ontology, reasoning

I have the following example instance of the `Brick.ttl` buildings ontology

```
@prefix : <https://example.org/ontologies/test#> .
@prefix brick: <https://brickschema.org/schema/1.1/Brick#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

:CH1_Active_Power_Sensor a owl:NamedIndividual,
    brick:Active_Power_Sensor ;
    brick:isPointOf :CH1 .

:CH1_Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor a owl:NamedIndividual,
    brick:Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor ;
    brick:isPointOf :CH1 .

:CH1_Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor a owl:NamedIndividual,
    brick:Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor ;
    brick:isPointOf :CH1 .

:CH2_Active_Power_Sensor a owl:NamedIndividual,
    brick:Active_Power_Sensor ;
    brick:isPointOf :CH2 .

:CH2_Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor a owl:NamedIndividual,
    brick:Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor ;
    brick:isPointOf :CH2 .

:CH3_Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor a owl:NamedIndividual,
    brick:Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor ;
    brick:isPointOf :CH3 .

:CH3_Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor a owl:NamedIndividual,
    brick:Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor ;
    brick:isPointOf :CH3 .


:CH1 a owl:NamedIndividual, brick:Chiller ;
    brick:hasPoint :CH1_Active_Power_Sensor ;
    brick:hasPoint :CH1_Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor ;
    brick:hasPoint :CH1_Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor .

:CH2 a owl:NamedIndividual, brick:Chiller ;
    brick:hasPoint :CH2_Active_Power_Sensor ;
    brick:hasPoint :CH2_Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor .

:CH3 a owl:NamedIndividual, brick:Chiller ;
    brick:hasPoint :CH3_Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor ;
    brick:hasPoint :CH3_Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor .
```

I need to identify instances which have a set of points, i.e. all brick:Chiller which has all members from {brick:Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor, brick:Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor} (and any others).

It's easy using SPARQL, i.e.

```
SELECT ?subject WHERE {
    ?subject brick:hasPoint ?p1 .
    ?p1 rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* brick:Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor .
    ?subject brick:hasPoint ?p2 .
    ?p2 rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* brick:Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor .
    }
```

But I have a lot of these combinations and I was hoping I could define them in such a way that it's possible to reason that :CH1 and :CH3 are a specific subtype so I can directly query for it. My attempt so far is:

```
:CHWETLT a owl:Class ;
    owl:equivalentClass [ 
        a owl:Restriction ;
        owl:onProperty :hasPoint ;
        owl:allValuesFrom [
            a owl:Class ;
            owl:intersectionOf (
                brick:Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor
                brick:Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor
            )
        ]
    ] .
```

I'm hoping that inference would identify that :CH1 and :CH3 belong to :CHWETLT so I can query for that directly. This doesn't seem to work though - I'm not sure where to go from now. Is this possible? If so can someone point me in the correct direction?

I'm using the `brickschema` python package which is (afaik) built on `rdflib` and uses `reasonable` as the reasoner.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you saying it's not minimal, reproducible or readable? I tried to balance all 3 but wasn't quite sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Manchester syntax, instead of

```
hasPoint only ( Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor and
                Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor )
```

you need rather

```
( hasPoint some Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor ) and
( hasPoint some Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor  )
```

Back to Turtle syntax:

```
:CHWETLT a owl:Class ;
    owl:equivalentClass [
        a owl:Class ;
        owl:intersectionOf (
            [ a owl:Restriction ;
              owl:onProperty brick:hasPoint ;
              owl:someValuesFrom brick:Chilled_Water_Entering_Temperature_Sensor
            ]
            [ a owl:Restriction ;
              owl:onProperty brick:hasPoint ;
              owl:someValuesFrom brick:Chilled_Water_Leaving_Temperature_Sensor
            ]
        ) 
    ] .
```

Strictly speaking, this axiom is outside [OWL 2 RL](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL_2). However, all you need for your inference is the left-to-right subsumption. Why OWL 2 RL? The `owlrl` Python reasoner [mentioned](https://github.com/BrickSchema/Brick#complexity) in the documentation supports only this OWL profile, I suppose.